# What is the role/permission for user to see the application UI that runs under SYSTEM account

Tags: windows, windows-services, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a Windows Service that automatically starts another WPF application ( from an .exe file)- I know this is not a good practice, however that is a requirement I got.

I am able now to start a UI application via Windows Service. This works fine on my local computer; I can see a UI and the application is running correctly. The application is running under the "SYSTEM" user as seen from the Windows Task Manager.

The problem only occurs when I move the code to our production computer, which is Windows Server 2012, and the account I use is given by our IT department (and it should have admin rights). After running the service, the application is running successfully; I can see it from the Task Manager. However, I cannot see the UI even though it is still running under "SYSTEM" account.

What sort of role or permission does a user need to see the UI application (or just an application in general) running under "SYSTEM" account?

Comment: Windows version of your local computer?

Comment: I has win 10 64 bit on my local computer

Comment: It doesn't really work that way, the application needs permissions to display a GUI to the user, the user doesn't need permissions to see the application.  I'm don't remember whether or not SYSTEM has the necessary permissions by default, this might change between versions of Windows.  The first thing to check though is whether the application is running in the right Remote Desktop session, you can do this with Task Manager - check the "Session ID" column, it should be same ID as other applications the user runs.

Comment: Also, does the application *need* to run as local system?  It would simplify things if the application was run as the user instead.

Comment: I can run the application under user account, the thing is I need to enable the "interact with desktop" ( I run the application via Windows Service). I have tried to manual enable the "interact with desktop" via registry but still doesn't work. That why application need to run as local system